# Как найти самое близкое расстояние в листе из точек по отношению к точке

Tags: unity3d, vector

Входные данные:

```
Vector3 point; 
//Vector3 это точка в пространстве x,y,z
List<Vector3> coordinates;
//массив Vector3
```

В цикле `foreach` нужно найти какая из точек в листе самая близкая к точке `point`.

Answer (score 0):

Не уж то в интернете нет решения настолько тривиальной задачи?

```
float minDist=float.maxValue;
int minNum=-1;
for(int i=list.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
{

  //можно просто magnitude
  float dist=(list[i]-point).sqrMagnitude;
  if(dist<minDist) {
    minDist=dist;
    minNum=i;
  }
}

Vector3 nearPoint;
if(minNum!=-1) nearPoint=list[minNum];
else nearPoint=Vector3.zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно решить и без цикла foreach в одну строку, использую мощное средство C# - LINQ.

```
Vector3 point; //Vector3 это точка в пространстве x,y,z
List<Vector3> coordinates; //массив Vector3

// Сперва ищем минимальное расстояние.
var resPointSqrMagnitude = coordinates.Select(p => (point - p).sqrMagnitude).Min();

// И находим ту точку, которая выдала это самое минимальное расстояние
var resultedPoint = coordinates.First(p => (point - p).sqrMagnitude == resPointSqrMagnitude);
```

Comment: как ты думаешь, что под капотом используется в LINQ? магия? или, всё же, циклы (ок, перебор значений итератором)?

Comment: И если точка окажется последняя в списке, то получим двойной обход координат и вычислений расстояния( добавим сюда 1000 точек и получим фриз на N ms). Неправильное использование LINQ убьет производительность в мгновение ока( в целом использование LINQ).

Comment: @Xumera_hZ `И если точка окажется последняя в списке, то получим двойной обход координат и вычислений расстояния( добавим сюда 1000 точек и получим фриз на N ms` - а разве твой обход циклом не страдает тем же недостатком? Ты обходишь с конца, но если нужный объект в начале, то...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, не страдает. Потому что у меня идет один проход по точкам и один просчет расстояния на одну точку списка, у тут сначало Select проход + вычисление, потом min проход + сравнение, потом еще раз проход + вычисление и сравнение.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ ты не понял, что я написал. ну да ладно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понял прекрасно, ну сделаю я поиск не с конца так с начала, точка может оказаться не в начале, так в конце, те же грабли. И если в его случае точка окажется в начале, то его поиск сведется к 2 проходам(вместо 3х), а мой как останется на одном проходе так и будет.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ а то, что код выше страдает избыточностью, это понятно)) на самом деле там можно его сократить, чтобы не было столько проходов, но это уже бог с ним)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Та можно конечно, все равно сведется в итоге к 1 проходу. Если только список изначально будет не монотонный. Вообще Linq удобно использовать если все равно на скорость выполнения, или делаешь что-нибудь не жрущее runtime(UI например), и там выборка <20 элементов по нескольким параметрам, вместо мусора из циклов, можно все лаконично записать.