# Найти ближний объект Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я сделал NavMeshAgent в Unity. И через for задал ему несколько целей. Уничтожает один объект, затем другой. Но, как я понял, он определяет не ближний объект, а по возрастанию (по индексу массива).

Как сделать так, чтобы персонаж определял ближний объект, затем уничтожил его, а потом переходил к другому ближнему?

Один человек посоветовал мне через magnitude, но работает некорректно.

Вот мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

private NavMeshAgent agent;
private GameObject[] target;
private Animator anim;
private float distance;

public Transform start;

void Start () {
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

public void Attack(int index){
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++) {
                distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, agent.steeringTarget);
                Vector3 move = target [i].transform.position;
                transform.LookAt (new Vector3 (target [i].transform.position.x, 0, target [i].transform.position.z));
                agent.SetDestination (move);
                agent.updateRotation = true;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        {
            anim.Play ("Idle Firing");
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (start.position, start.forward, out hit, 100.0f)) {
                Debug.Log (hit.point);
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Target") {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Building> ().health -= 1;
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Building> ().health <= 0) {
                        Destroy (hit.collider.gameObject);
                        anim.Play ("Idle");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Debug.LogError ("Error");
            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        {
            anim.Play ("Idle");
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void Navigate(){
    for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++) {
        distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, agent.steeringTarget);
        if (distance > agent.stoppingDistance) {
            anim.Play ("Run_Forwards");
        }
    }
}

void Shoot(){
    Attack (0);
    if (distance > agent.stoppingDistance) {
        Navigate ();
    } else if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance) {
        Attack (1);
    } else {
        anim.Play ("Idle");
    }
}

void Update () {
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Target");
    Shoot ();
}
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698715/Как-найти-самое-близкое-расстояние-в-листе-из-точек-по-отношению-к-точке несколькими вопросами ранее...

Answer (score 4):

Здравствуйте!

Немного теории.

Допустим есть ваш персонаж и две цели куда идти. Первая цель `target1` находится на расстоянии в 2 метра от персонажа, а вторая `target2` в 5 метрах. Но есть одно условие, первая цель `target1` стоит за длинной стеной, а вторая `target2` в зоне прямой видимости от персонажа. Если применять ваши методы сравнения `Vector3.Distance` или `Vector3.Magnitude`, то будет выдаваться первая цель `target1`, но она за стеной и идти до нее 8 метров!

Мораль сей басни такова: вам нужно проверять не расстояние, а длину пути до объекта. Пример кода :

```
IEnumerator GetClosestTarget() {
    float tmpDist = float.MaxValue;
    GameObject currentTarget = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++) {
        if (agent.SetDestination(targets[i].transform.position)) {
            //ждем пока вычислится путь до цели
            while (agent.pathPending) {
                yield return null;
            }
            Debug.Log(agent.pathStatus.ToString());
            // проверяем, можно ли дойти до цели
            if (agent.pathStatus != NavMeshPathStatus.PathInvalid) {
                float pathDistance = 0;
                //вычисляем длину пути
                pathDistance += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, agent.path.corners[0]);
                for (int j = 1; j < agent.path.corners.Length; j++) {
                    pathDistance += Vector3.Distance(agent.path.corners[j - 1], agent.path.corners[j]);
                }

                if (tmpDist > pathDistance) { 
                    tmpDist = pathDistance;
                    currentTarget = targets[i];
                    agent.ResetPath();
                }
            } else {
                Debug.Log("невозможно дойти до "+ targets[i].name);
            }

        }

    }
    if (currentTarget != null) {
        agent.SetDestination(currentTarget.transform.position);
        //... дальше ваша логика движения к цели
    }
}
```

Вызов этого метода производится так: `StartCoroutine(GetClosestTarget());`

Answer (score 1):

Найти ближний объект можно так:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Nearest : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject [] enemy;
    GameObject closest;

    public string nearest;

    void Start() {
        enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    }

    GameObject FindClosestEnemy() {
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in enemy) {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if(curDistance< distance) {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }

    void Update() {
        nearest =FindClosestEnemy().name;
    }
}
```

Тут:

`GameObject [] enemy;` - список объектов врагов, среди которых будем искать.

`FindClosestEnemy()` - ищет ближайший GameObject к объекту на который повешен скрипт.

Надо отметить врагов Tag `("Enemy")`. Для формирования списка в котором будем искать ближайший объект, находящийся относительно нашего.

Не стал заморачиваться, чтоб переделывать ваш код. Так как вопрос старый. Решил поделиться кодом который у меня хорошо работает.

Answer (score 0):

Идеологически можно подойти к решению 2 способами:

1. Один раз найти ближайшую цель, запомнить ее и двигаться в ее направлении до тех пор, пока она не будет уничтожена
2. Каждый раз при вызове Update() пересчитывать расстояния и каждый раз искать ближайшую цель. Это может быть точнее, чем первый вариант, потому что будет учитывать скорость перемещения целей (если они движутся, и если они движутся с разной скоростью), однако требует пересчета при каждом вызове Update, в силу чего менее оптимально, чем первый вариант.

Однако, стоит заметить, что вам посоветовали верный способ поиска ближайшей цели (использование magnitude) Вы также можете попробовать [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html), но судя по документации, этот метод работает через magnitude. Или можете попробовать [Vector3.sqrMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html), он схож по идее работы с magnitude, но работает чуть быстрее, за счет того, что не выполняется операция вычисления квадратного корня, однако в силу этого дает менее точный результат. Вы можете почитать обсуждения на тему методов поиска ближайшего объекта [здесь](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/clean-est-way-to-find-nearest-object-of-many-c.44315/) и [здесь](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/384932/best-way-to-find-distance.html).

Вам может казаться результат вычисления ближайшей цели неверным, если работаете с вычислениями через Vector3, так как он работает с 3 измерениями (А скорее всего речь идет именно о трехмерной игре, так как вы используете навигацию Unity). Например, если взять игру с видом сверху, то учет разности высот при измерении расстояния может казаться визуально неверным, но точным математически. Таким образом вы можете попробовать считать расстояния с помощью тех же методов magnitude, sqrMagnitude или Distance, но используя Vector2. Тогда при вычислении расстояния учитываться будут только x и y координаты объектов. Такой подход может дать более "верное" решение задачи с точки зрения визуальной части.